# How to transform X and Y coordinate on a delimited text imported layer

Tags: qgis, coordinates, excel

I added excel sheets into my project using the deliminted tab and used the X and Y columns that are in a mercator coordinate system, I am using QGIS 3.14. These layers are not showing up in my project because another layer that I have in the project is in a different coordinate system. Showed in the picture below. The attribute table for this layer has the same X and Y coordinates as the excel sheets I brought into the project.
How do I transform the layers I brought in to match the transformation done to the layer that was supplied to me?
[image]

The layers that I imported from excel and the layer that was supplied to me have the same X and Y coordinates in the attribute table. Would saving the attribute table from the supplied and bringing it back into the project through the delimited tab work to fix the transformation issues?
[image]

Comment: How do they not align with the basemap?  Are they off by a few meters, or on the other side of the planet?  Upside down?  Reversed?  Also, it would really help if you would edit your question by typing several lines from your .csv file.

Comment: What coordinate reference system is your XY data, canvas and other data that doesn't align? My first guess would be that the XY data is undefined which makes it impossible to project-on-the-fly to align data. As @StuSmith said, a bit of clarification and a few lines from your spreadsheet would really help otherwise we'd be only guessing.

Comment: Very probably one of these often asked questions where wrong CRS settings are the problem. For example: if the coordinate values are not within the range of +/- 180 for x-values and +/- 90 for y-values, it's clear that you can't load them with EPSG:4326 definition for the CRS. But as mentioned before: provide more information and some sample values of your coordinates.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a transformation from EPSG:26905 to 3857. Did you try to  load the coordinates in one of those CRS? Than maybe try 4326 (if you have lat/lon values). But be aware - even with lat/lon values you can have an offset of hundreds of meters or more, depending on which elipsoid is used for the CRS the data is defined in, e.g. EPSG-codes 4326 (WGS84) vs. 4314 (Bessel 1841).

Comment: As a test I should try loading the Excel file into QGIS, then right-click on it in the layers panel and set its CRS to ESPG:4326. Then set the *project* CRS to EPSG:4326 as well. Then add your Bing aerial base map to see where the points plot.

The coordinates in the Excel are lon-lat (probably EPSG:4326) and I think that what you might have done is specify the wrong CRS (EPSG:26905) when trying to import the data.